# SQL Server log Size increasing while in Simple recovery mode

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Is it possible to locate the active transaction, it was not listed in `DBCC opentran`, the log file keeps getting bigger.

1. Database is in Simple recovery
2. tried shrinking the database - no luck

Also we have restarted the SQL service, no improvement the log file size keeps increasing.

Comment: How do you know it was because of an active transaction?  Was `sys.databases.log_reuse_wait_desc` actually set to `ACTIVE_TRANSACTION`?

Comment: from the sys.databases.log_reuse_wait_desc it was showing 'replication' but the Database was not configured for any replication.